# Multi Frame app comes to error after returning back to the app

Tags: nativescript

this my app.js

```
import Vue       from "nativescript-vue";
import Center    from "./components/Center";

new Vue( { 
    render (h) { 
        return h( Center )
    }
} ).$start();
```

***Center*** component contains ***Menu*** component which has been nested in its own Frame:

this is ***Center*** component:

```
<template>
<Frame actionBarVisibility="never">
    <Page class="mainCutton" ref="mainCutton" @swipe="onSwipe">
        <GridLayout>

               ... 

            <Menu ref="Menu" />

        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</Frame>
</template>
```

and finally this is ***Menu*** component:

```
<template>
<Frame actionBarVisibility="never" ref="menuFrame">
    <page class="vivid">
        <GridLayout>
            ...
        </GridLayout>
    </page>
</Frame>
</template>
```

the problem is this: when I switch off the device screen, and then **immediately** turn on the phone ( the app is running still ) I got this error:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to resume activity ...: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x2 (unknown) for fragment fragment8[8]<Page(85)>
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity ...: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x2 (unknown) for fragment fragment8[8]<Page(85)>
```

but if the phone has some time before switching on ( like 1-2 sec ) it will **NOT** come to any error.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=HYKPIo

just try to unlock your phone as fast as you can, after some try you will get the error.

I got this:

An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x2 (unknown) for fragment fragment12[12]<Page(12)>
...

Comment: I did try on Google Pixel, couldn't see the exception. Which device / OS version you are testing it on? Did you also try on various devices?

Comment: on Redmi Note 8, Pie, MIUI 11 weekly BETA.

Comment: It also works just fine on my Huawei Tablet, so How can I solve this on my Redmi Device?